# Embedding Scontrol on Visual Force page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to embed scontrol into a VF page through  tag but it's giving an error that scontrol name is invalid. I've checked and verified that I'm giving a valid API name for the scontrol. Plz help. i've used the apex tag as follows:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:scontrol controlName="my_scontrol_API_name"/>
</apex:page>
```

The error I'm getting is that scontrol name is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:scontrol controlName="My_S_Control" />
</apex:page>
```

Are you sure you're using the *exact* S-Control name? Check to make sure in Setup > Develop > S-Controls > [Your S-Control].

Comment: I copy pasted the scontrol name. Is it the case that <apex:scontrol> tag can only be used under the <apex:page> tag? I'll try it tomorrow morning. Another thing is that the scontrol has a package added into it. Would that create a problem?

Comment: I'm not sure on either of your follow up questions. Maybe someone else in the community would know. Hope you find your answer!

Answer (score 0):

S-Controls are deprecated.
I hope [this link](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/S-Control_Deprecation) will help you.